# Google analytics geoid tag correct usage

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics to provide insights on use of an IoT device. The code I've got works fine and it picks up the location data automatically. When I add geoid tag though it is nulling to location.

I guess I'm doing something wrong. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Here is the code I'm using with geoid at the end:
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-12345678-1&cid=abc123&t=pageview&dp=MyDevice&geoid=1000339

Comment: Have you made sure its listed?  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/geoid

Comment: Yes. I tried several of the Criteria ID from that list but none work. Every time I add one it simply null's the location and 'hit' is recorded on Google Analytics without a location.

Comment: The issue appears to be in the location's criteria ID. Even though the one I was using was on the spreadsheet and listed as valid, when I tried several others they worked (it took a FEW goes to select on that worked..).

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be in the location's criteria ID. 
Even though the ones I tried were on the spreadsheet and listed as valid, when I tried others they worked (it took a FEW goes to randomly select on that worked..).

Comment: I will log this as a bug and link it back here

Comment: I submitted this as a possible bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38300576

Comment: Locations with criteria ID starting with a 1 that I've tested are OK, those starting in a 9 are not. Not exhaustive testing, but pattern worth checking out.